# ROBLOX LUA(u) passing argument of table = nil (attempt to concatenate nil with string)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a DB, still in testing phrase, but:
As you can see, it's basically unpacking a table gives us "nil".

It's a strange error I've not been able to fix.

[image: Photo error]

Testing ServerScriptService Script:

```lua
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ServerStorage = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local Greenwich = require(ServerStorage:WaitForChild("Greenwich"))

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    
    Player.Chatted:Connect(function(Message)
        
        if Message == "t" then
            
            local ServerName = script.Name
            print("T has been recognized by "..ServerName)
            
            print(Greenwich:GetDB("salvage"))
            warn(Greenwich:GetDB("salvage"):Set("MyKey", "MyValue"))
            
            print("Finalized.")
            
        end
        
    end)
    
end)
```

Module Scirpt:

```lua
--Variables
local dss = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local db = dss:GetDataStore("greenwich")

-- Tables
local greenwich = {}
local dbFunctions = {}

--Functions
function greenwich:GetDB(name)
    local new = {}
    coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
        for k, v in pairs(dbFunctions) do
            new[k] = function(...)
                local args = { ... }
                return v(name, unpack(args))
            end
        end
    end))
    return new
end

function dbFunctions:Set(save_key, key, value)
    save_key = unpack(save_key)
    db:SetAsync(
        save_key..
            key,
        value)
    return value
end

--Returning everything.
return greenwich
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save_key` is a the same table as `new`

`save_key = unpack(save_key)` assings `nil` to `save_key`

`unpack(save_key)` returns `nil` as `save_key` is not a sequence.

`unpack (list [, i [, j]])` is equivalent to `return list[i], list[i+1],..,list[j]`
where
`i` and `j` default to `1` and `#list`

The only field in `new` is `new["Set"]`.